# Topological Band Representations

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

I have a question regarding the little group representations on the topologicalquantumchemistry webpage. There is a link for the compound RhSi below. The site lists representations like 6+7 (4), which I interpret as taking the Kronecker sum of the Gamma6 and Gamma7 representations (both 2-dimensional, and listed on the Bilbao webserver linked on the Gamma symbol), having the dimension 4 in total.
Now my issue is, that this 4 dimensional representation belongs to a 4-fold degeneracy. But the 6+7 (4) representation is seperable in 2x2 blocks, and I do not see why it should be 4-fold dimensional rather than having 2 times a 2-fold degenerate intersection at different energies. The 4-fold intersection seems not accidental.

I interpret that for a given representation, for example, 5 (2), the whole corresponding column of matrices on the Bilbao server are viable symmetry operations on Gamma.
I then interpret that for 6+7 (4), any combination of the two corresponding rows, added via Kronecker sum, corresponds to a viable symmetry operation.

My question is still, why is it a 4-fold degeneracy, rather than a 2 times 2-fold one?

https://www.topologicalquantumchemistry.com/#/detail/24719

Comment: Is it something more complicated than observing that $2*2=4$?

Comment: I want to create a kp Hamiltonian, which I know to be not block diagonal.
It is not 2*2, but 2+2, this is for sure. There are representations that could not be originating from the Kronecker product on the same site.